# Form Submission Email

Tags: cognito-forms

When I change a submission form from reviewed to completed it sends me another email with the submission again.
Is there a way to turn this off?
I only want an email when the initial form is submitted.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that your notification emails are set to send when the entry status is updated. Open up Submission Settings in your builder and ensure that the Send When Updated option is set to Never:

[image]

If this is not the case, I would recommend submitting a [support request](https://www.cognitoforms.com/supportrequest/) to Cognito Forms so they can look into your issue more closely.